# Easier Method? Solving difficult differential?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am currently doing a differentiation problem, and was wondering whether there is a faster and less complicated way to arrive to the output.

$$\frac{x^2\arccos(e^{-x^3})}{\sqrt{\tan{(x^2)} + \cos{(4x)}^4}}$$

Currently, I have to differentiate the denominator, which requires multiple differentiations in itself & then I have to do the numerator also.

So is there a faster way?

EDIT:

This is what I have currently done:

**$u' = 2x\ arccos{(e^{-x^3})}\ + x^2(\frac{-3x^2 * \ e^{-x^3}}{\sqrt{1-(e^{-2x^3})}})$**

**$v' = \frac{2x\ sec^2{(x^2)}-16\ cos^3{(4x)\ * \ sin(4x)}}{2\ \sqrt{tan{(x^2)} \ + cos{(4x)}^4}}$**

Comment: Logarithmic differentiation will save a little bit of pain but not much.

Comment: @Ian I'm not that great at maths, so I was wondering whether this would be classified as a 'hard problem'? The issue is I find it very hard to keep track of the multiple differentiation that I need to do..

Comment: It's messy and long, not so much hard. But logarithmic differentiation does make it easier to keep track of what you still need to differentiate.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for the input & suggestion. Might give it a try.Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed an easier method: take every instance of $x$ in turn, consider the others as constant, and form the sum.

$$\frac{x^2\arccos(e^{-x^3})}{\sqrt{\tan{(x^2)} \ +\cos{(4x)}^4}}$$

yields

$$\frac{\color{green}{2x}\arccos(e^{-x^3})}{\sqrt{\tan{(x^2)} \ +\cos{(4x)}^4}}+\\
\frac{x^2\color{green}{\dfrac{-3x^2e^{-x^3}}{-\sqrt{1-e^{-2x^3}}}}}{\sqrt{\tan{(x^2)}+\cos{(4x)}^4}}+\\
\color{green}{-\frac12\frac{2x}{\cos^2(x^2)}}\frac{x^2\arccos(e^{-x^3})}{\color{green}{\left(\sqrt{\tan{(x^2)} \ +\cos{(4x)}^4}\right)^3}}+\\
\color{green}{\frac124(4x)^3\sin((4x)^4)}\frac{x^2\arccos(e^{-x^3})}{\color{green}{\left(\sqrt{\tan{(x^2)} \ +\cos{(4x)}^4}\right)^3}}.\\
$$

Comment: Wow! This is amazing! If it isn't too much trouble, could you please direct me to where you learnt this method.

Comment: It is just a bookkeeping technique for the product rule, essentially.

Comment: @Ian Is there a specific name given to this technique? I would love to know more about it.

Comment: @user36278: I saw it on... Mathematics. This is a consequence of the differentiation of functions of several variables. $df(x,y)=f_x(x,y)dx+f_y(x,y)dy$ then $df(x,x)=f_x(x,x)dx+f_y(x,x)dx$.

Comment: @Ian: it's wider than that. Consider $x^x$.

Comment: Fair point. That's neat.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on where the power of 3 came from. It gets a bit confusing for the bottom two sums.

Comment: @user36278: from the power $4$.

Comment: Minor typo: the second term has $2x$ which should be $x^2$.  And I thiiiiink the last term should be a double negative, i.e. positive.

Comment: @ErickWong: thank you for the careful proofreading, I have fixed. Typesetting such large expressions drives you mad :)

Answer (score 1):

HINT, use:

1. $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{\text{f}(x)}{\text{g}(x)}\right)=\frac{\text{g}(x)\text{f}'(x)-\text{f}(x)\text{g}'(x)}{\text{g}(x)^2}$$
2. $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\text{r}(x)\cdot\text{z}(x)\right)=\text{z}(x)\text{r}'(x)+\text{r}(x)\text{z}'(x)$$
3. $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\text{a}(x)+\text{b}(x)\right)=\text{a}'(x)+\text{b}'(x)$$
4. When $\text{n}$ is a constant:
   $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x^\text{n}\right)=\text{n}x^{\text{n}-1}$$
5. $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sqrt{\text{q}(x)}\right)=\frac{\text{q}'(x)}{2\sqrt{\text{q}(x)}}$$
6. $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\arccos\left(\text{v}(x)\right)\right)=-\frac{\text{v}'(x)}{\sqrt{1-\text{v}(x)^2}}$$
7. $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\tan\left(\text{c}(x)\right)\right)=\text{c}'(x)\sec^2\left(\text{c}(x)\right)$$
8. $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\cos\left(\text{k}(x)\right)\right)=-\text{k}'(x)\sin\left(\text{k}(x)\right)$$

---

EDIT, using the rules from above:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{\text{h}(x)\cdot\text{L}(x)}{\sqrt{\text{m}(x)+\text{p}(x)}}\right)=$$
$$\frac{\left(\sqrt{\text{m}(x)+\text{p}(x)}\right)\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\text{h}(x)\cdot\text{L}(x)\right)-\left(\text{h}(x)\cdot\text{L}(x)\right)\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sqrt{\text{m}(x)+\text{p}(x)}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{\text{m}(x)+\text{p}(x)}\right)^2}=$$
$$\frac{\left(\sqrt{\text{m}(x)+\text{p}(x)}\right)\cdot\left(\text{h}'(x)\cdot\text{L}(x)+\text{h}(x)\cdot\text{L}'(x)\right)-\left(\text{h}(x)\cdot\text{L}(x)\right)\cdot\frac{\text{m}'(x)+\text{p}'(x)}{2\sqrt{\text{m}(x)+\text{p}(x)}}}{\left(\sqrt{\text{m}(x)+\text{p}(x)}\right)^2}$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, I was wondering whether there was a faster way to solve these kinds of problems?

Comment: @user36278 No there isn't, you need to use the rules of the derivatives.

Comment: Do you have any tips on how I can keep track of all my differentiations, because I am finding it quite hard.

Comment: @user36278 Yes, I will edit my answer.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help.Thank-you!